# Spring cloud slueth SpanAccessor interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am inject SpanAccessor interface from Spring Cloud Slueth, the version I am using is 1.3.3, I want to upgrade to version 2.1.1 where that interface is removed. There is no documentation on what alternate I can use to get this of the SpanAccessor I am using. any ideas on how to go around this issue?

this what I am currently doing:

```
@Inject
private SpanAccessor spanAccessor;
```

and then using it like this:

```
spanAccessor.getCurrentSpan().toString().split(",");
```

No documentation available to refactor this to something that can give me current span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject and use `SpanCustomizer` interface to customize the current span (add tags / logs etc.) or inject and use `Tracing` to retrieve the current span ad manipulate it.

Comment: I dont see any Tracer interface in the the latest version

Comment: I'm sorry I meant `Tracing` from Brave's library

Comment: There is brave.Tracer do you think I can use that? it has a getCurrentSpan function

Comment: also, the Span will also be used from brave?

Comment: Correct. BTW all of this is desrcibed in the project readme and documentation. Please read it. Can we mark this question as answered?